# Splitting Polygons with Lines in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I'm trying to use the split polygons with lines tool found [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cd6b2d45df654245b7806a896670a431) in ArcGIS Pro to subdivide a city's corporate boundary (polygon) with a street centerlines layer (lines) in order to subdivide the city into its blocks.

[image]

However, when I run it, the results are just the city's corporate boundary, the line geometry hasn't had any effect:

[image]

Any idea what I can do to get the results I'm looking for?